# Is there any difference between Standalone applications and Markup-only XAML applications?

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight-4.0, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

Is there any difference between Standalone applications and Markup-only XAML applications in respect to WPF?

I am reading the following link where I got reference of these two application however for deployment perspective but is there really any difference between these two?

[`Deploying a WPF Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969776%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Are you asking about differences in deployment?  Otherwise can you be more specific as to what you are looking to compare?

Comment: No In general.. Is there any difference irrespective of deployment ? In which scenario we need standalone application or Markup-only XAML application

Comment: What actions will do your application? Tell us more about your application.

Comment: No I am not creating any application but for curosity I want to understand the difference between them..

Answer (score 1):

Differences, reasons and scenarios are explained in the official MS documentation. I think there isn't much more to add.

From [Deploying a WPF Application (WPF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969776%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Deploying WPF Applications**

The deployment options for a WPF application depend on the type of application. From a deployment perspective, WPF has three significant application types:

- Standalone applications
- Markup-only XAML applications
- XAML browser applications (XBAPs)

**Deploying Standalone Applications**

Standalone applications are deployed using either ClickOnce or Windows Installer. Either way, standalone applications require full trust to run. Full trust is automatically granted to standalone applications that are deployed using Windows Installer. Standalone applications that are deployed using ClickOnce are not automatically granted full trust. Instead, ClickOnce displays a security warning dialog that users must accept before a standalone application is installed. If accepted, the standalone application is installed and granted full trust. If not, the standalone application is not installed.

**Deploying Markup-Only XAML Applications**

Markup-only XAML pages are usually published to Web servers, like HTML pages, and can be viewed using Internet Explorer. Markup-only XAML pages run within a partial-trust security sandbox with restrictions that are defined by the Internet zone permission set. This provides an equivalent security sandbox to HTML-based Web applications. Markup-only XAML pages can be installed to the local file system by using either XCopy or Windows Installer. These pages can be viewed using Internet Explorer or Windows Explorer.

**Deploying XAML Browser Applications**

XBAPs are compiled applications that require the following three files to be deployed:

- ApplicationName.exe: The executable assembly application file
- ApplicationName.xbap: The deployment manifest
- ApplicationName.exe.manifest: The application manifest

These files are produced when an XBAP is built. Like markup-only XAML pages, XBAPs are typically published to a Web server and viewed using Internet Explorer.

XBAPs can be deployed to clients using any of the deployment techniques. However, ClickOnce is recommended since it provides the following capabilities:

- Automatic updates when a new version is published
- Elevation privileges for the XBAP running with full trust

By default, ClickOnce publishes application files with the .deploy extension. This can be problematic, but can be disabled. For more information, see Server and Client Configuration Issues in ClickOnce Deployments.

Comment: Thanks Neurone.. but this is something at deployment perspective.. I want to understand why should I go for Maarkup-only XAML or standalone application.. OR the difference lies ONLY in DEPLOYMENT perspective ..